# How to use the word "food" in the plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is it correct and totally colloquial to ask someone "What are your favourite foods and drinks?" in order to ask about what different foods and drinks they like, not meaning the dishes? or should one use those words in the singular?

Comment: It depends on context and style. You could say *food items* or you could say *foods*. Some people don't like to say *foods*, but it's both grammatical and, in some cases, idiomatic.

Comment: Generally, one would say: What is your favorite food and drink? But Jason is right, it depends. I usually think of it as one type or category of food.

Comment: Would you then answer that question saying: "My favourite food is chicken and cookies and my favourite drink is orange juice and milk"?

Comment: _Food_ is a mass noun, and one of the things that pluralizing mass nouns does is refer to **varieties** of the noun. So _foods_ means 'different kinds of food'. As for an interview question, if you're worried about nouns, use verbs -- _What do you like to eat and drink?_ You can ask _What kinds of things_ if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the sentence you posted (although it sounds a little "heavy" to say), but to be totally colloquial, depending on the context of course, I'd go with something like:

> What kind of food and drink do you like?

When asking someone's favourite, I feel that food and drink would rarely be asked about  together, but separately as:

> What's your favourite food?
>
> What are your favourite foods?
>
> What's your favourite drink?
>
> What are your favourite drinks?

If you were interested in them both together, and how they compliment one another, it would probably be asked as:

> What's your favourite food and drink combination?

Or you could even say "combo" instead of "combination", to be ultra-colloquial. :)